Resolving dependencies independently of the IoC container
I'm working on a component, let's call it MyComponent, which is intended to be used by various applications. These applications will get MyComponent as a NuGet package for instance.
Assume that MyComponent is a business logic for user management with the following public API:
namespace MyComponent.API.Users.Queries.GetUser;

public record UserModel(string Name, string Email);

public interface IGetUsersQuery
{
    IReadOnlyList<UserModel> Execute();
}

namespace MyComponent.API.Services.Database;

public record UserData(int Id, string Name, string Email, string PasswordHash);

public interface IDatabaseService
{
    IList<UserData> Users { get; set; }

    void Save();
}

The IGetUsersQuery interface is part of the business logic, so it is implemented internally by MyComponent:
namespace MyComponent.Users.Queries.GetUser;

internal class GetUsersQuery(IDatabaseService database) : IGetUsersQuery
{
    public IReadOnlyList<UserModel> Execute()
    {
        return database.Users.Select(ToUserModel).ToList();
    }
    
    private static UserModel ToUserModel(UserData userData)
    {
        return new UserModel(userData.Name, userData.Email);
    }
}

MyComponent requires the application using it, let's call it SomeApplication, to implement the IDatabaseService:
namespace SomeApplication.Persistence;

internal class DatabaseService : IDatabaseService
{
    public IList<UserData> Users { get; set; } = new List<UserData>();

    public void Save()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All changes are saved");
    }
}

SomeApplication can query users by implementing some kind of controller that depends on the IGetUsersQuery interface:
namespace SomeApplication.Presentation.Users;

internal class UsersController(IGetUsersQuery query)
{
    public void ShowUsers()
    {
        foreach(var user in query.Execute())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(user);
        }
    }
}

It is clear that MyComponent depends on an interface that SomeApplication implements, and vice versa.
Assume that SomeApplication uses the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection to resolve dependencies. If the implementations in MyComponent were public, then SomeApplication would have an easy job:
private static ServiceProvider CreateServices()
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<IGetUsersQuery, GetUsersQuery>()
        .AddSingleton<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>()
        .AddSingleton<UsersController>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    return serviceProvider;
}


How can I make SomeApplication resolve dependencies on interfaces in MyComponent if the implementations are internal?
How can MyComponent be independent of the dependency injection solution used by SomeApplication, if any?

I also thought about using reflection, but I would avoid this approach, because it would make SomeApplication depend on implementation details of MyComponent.

Microsoft have defined a standard pattern for this scenario;  Most of the modern. popular .NET libraries tend to follow these guidelines:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options-library-authors

Also - you can get a good idea of how this is done out "in the wild" by doing a GitHub search for the latest source for some of the Microsoft.Extensions.* packages (The file/class names usually end in *ServiceCollectionExtensions - e.g.  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs or https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/src/LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

Seems very similar: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/222707/289095

the way you lay out your example is super confusing for me. Let me see if ive got it straight.
You have two projects
MyComponent
- public IDatabaseService
- public IGetUsersQuery
- internal GetUsersQuery : IGetUsersQuery

SomeApplication
- internal DatabaseService : IDatabaseService
- internal UsersController

Obviously here SomeApplication can't instantiate a GetUsersQuery its internal,  it will never work, regardless of any dependencies.
But the way you talk about MyComponent, it seems like you should have at least one public class in the library!
If we posit an extra public class:
public class MyComponent
{
    public MyComponent(IGetUsersQuery query) {..}
}

This is also useless. Without a factory class or something it's pointless to have a public constructor that requires an internal parameter.
But. We could have:
public class MyComponent
{
    public MyComponent(IDatabaseService db) 
    {
       this.query = new GetUsersQuery(db);
    }
}

Now everything works. SomeApplication can do..
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddSingleton<IDatabaseService, DatabaseService>()
    .AddSingleton<MyComponent>()
    .BuildServiceProvider();

And we are good.
If you want to expose a way for the consumer to override the query, add an extra constructor
public class MyComponent
{
    public MyComponent(IDatabaseService db) 
    {
       this.query = new GetUsersQuery(db);
    }
    public MyComponent(IGetUsersQuery query) { this.query = query;}

}

Alternatively, microsoft are super keen on extension methods for DI despite my disapproval.
public static DiExtMeth
{
   public static AddMyComponent(this ServiceCollection dc) 
    {
      //whatever you have to do to make it work
      //resolve IDatabaseService from teh service collection, they will probably have added it
      //hope that people can find the namespace for this!
      //silently use defaults if you cant find what you need.
      //read straight out of appsettings!
    }
} 

Then you can make all your constructors internal and really lock down the way people use your component. But make it easy for tutorials

Good answer. I think it would not hurt to take the time to give the OP a direct answer to their questions. In short, the answer to "How can I make SomeApplication resolve dependencies on interfaces in MyComponent if the implementations are internal?" is - you don't let SomeApplication do this, instead you let MyComponent resolve the dependency manually, without any IoC container.

tbh im not 100% its what they are looking for, afterall i had to invent a class here

I think the alternative would be to make a classic Singleton implementation of  "GetUsersQuery", or to add a public "GetUsersQueryFactory". If one wants to have an IoC container agnostic implementation, it's best to make an implementation without an IoC container. a.k.a "manual DI".

Yeah, I think MS are downplaying the singleton defaults recently though, they got rid of the one in app insights telemetry. + i hate static :)

@DocBrown, creating a public factory for the IGetUsersQuery interface would solve my problem. So you would associate a public factory with each public interface, right? My concern with this approach is the lifetime of the instances. For example, the knowledge of whether a GetUsersQuery instance is singleton or not is internal, but if that instance is created by a factory, then SomeApplication should also know its intended lifetime to register it properly, e.g. AddSingleton<IGetUsersQuery>(sp => GetUsersQueryFactory.Create(sp.GetRequiredService<IDatabaseService>())).

My other idea would be to create adapters for each DI container framework that MyComponent would allow to access its internal types (InternalsVisibleTo). What do you think about this? My concern with this is that it violates the open-closed principle, since each time I implement a new adapter, I would have to modify MyComponent to add the new adapter as a friend.

An internal class is allowed to implement a public interface in C#. I honestly don't see a problem here, provided you follow a few rules:

The IDatabaseService is a public member of the assembly containing MyComponent.
Dependencies are registered in a DI container in the application, not the component. For a .NET application this is likely something in Program.cs, Startup.cs or Global.aspx.cs. Now your initialization code has access to internal types. Problem solved.

MyComponent can declare any public interfaces it needs. This provides types that other components and applications can implement to integrate with MyComponent. This is a perfectly valid thing to do. The trick is to adhere to the Dependency Inversion Principle. The application depends on the component, not the other way around. The application initializes all the bits and bobs required to run the silly thing. It has access to configuration and the DI container. MyComponent should be agnostic of a DI container and only declare the interfaces it requires, leaving it up to the code using MyComponent to provide implementations that are internal or external.
